# How do i disable multiple item selection via CTRL+click in QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have an instance of a class that inherits from QTableWidget in my Qt application. I'd like it to have a feature of multiple item selection via using click+drag sequence (i have that feature and it works fine), but i'd also like to disable CTRL+click sequence. How would i do that?

Comment: I suggest, that post a minimal-reproducible-example. It would also help yourself.

Comment: Did you try to set a selection mode? Look at `QAbstractItemView::SelectionMode` to see available options, especially `QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection`.

Comment: @vahancho SingleSelection will not allow the click+drag selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on what you want exactly.

The easiest way is to change the `selectionMode` to `QAbstractItemView::ContiguousSelection`. That way you will have the click-drag sequence.
However, Ctrl-click will still be active, but it will behave like a shift-click.

If you really want to disable the Ctrl-click, the only way is to override the `mousePress()` or `mouseRelease()` event and filter them out.